# Get json value in lua using cjson

Tags: nginx, lua, cjson

I have a json string encoded using json in lua for nginx. I have used cjson for encoding
I need to get value of a json key.

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": value2,
  "content": {
    "key4": "value4"
    }
}
}
```

How to get the value of key4 in lua.

So i have following

```
local encodedjson = cjson.encode(jwt_obj)
```

How do i extract value4 from encodedjson variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lua cjson library can take a JSON string and convert it into a Lua table using `cjson.decode`.

Once you have decoded the JSON string you can index the table with the keys. `json_table.content.key4`

Please note that numeric keys in a JSON file will always be represented as a string key in a lua table

i.e: `t['1']` not `t[1]`

References:
[Lua CJSON: 3.3 decode](https://www.kyne.com.au/%7Emark/software/lua-cjson-manual.html#_decode)